# Starting of tomcat Version 6 failed at port 8443 after configuring https

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to configure my tomcat to deploy applications through https://. It has been working on http so far. I created the keystore file under the config folder of tomcat.

**keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -noprompt -alias tomcat -dname "CN=localhost, OU=NA, O=NA, L=NA, S=NA, C=NA" -keystore keystore.jks -validity 9999 -storepass changeme -keypass changeme**

I changed the server.xml file:

**Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" keyAlias="tomcat" keystoreFile="conf/keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeme" clientAuth="false" acceptCount="100" sslProtocol="TLS"**

But my tomcat refuses to start. I am using NetBeans IDE and trying to start the server  from there. I do not see any errors in the logs.

However, if I edit the server.xml to redirect from 8080 to 443, tomcat starts but still deploys application through http:// and not https://  :

**Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443" disableUploadTimeout="false"
Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" keyAlias="tomcat" keystoreFile="conf/keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeme" clientAuth="false" acceptCount="100" sslProtocol="TLS"**

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of commenting with unformatted stuff _under_ your question, please _edit_ your question, use the formatting options ([ask]). Also, please note that Stackoverflow focuses on questions about programming ([help/on-topic]), while this one seems to be configuration related.

Comment: Your question also lacks version information: what version of Tomcat are you using, what OS, how you start Tomcat (as a Windows service, `startup.sh/catalina.sh`)? Tomcat generates many log files: unless you have severe file permission problems, they must contain something.

Comment: Are you really using Tomcat 6 or is it a typo?

Comment: I am using tomcat 6, it's not a typo